# How should I edit my question (that you closed as too broad), so as it could be reopened?

Tags: support, closed-questions

This question: [Does drinking water after eating watermelon cause cholera?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22241/does-drinking-water-or-milk-after-eating-fish-watermelon-muskmelon-or-corn-cau) has been closed by you. I am not aware of the rules and policies of this website--neither I want to know them. So please tell me how should I edit my question so as it will be appropriate for this website. I would also appreciate if someone else edit my question in such a way that it could be reopened.

My main question is
"*What are the experiments done on the human body that falsify these(harmful effects of drinking water after eating water melon) myths?*"

All the remaining portion can be deleted/edited in any way. If my question cannot be reopened in any way then please delete my question and my account too. I am not interesting in any kind of discussion of your policies.

Comment: "neither I want to know them" - the StackExcahnge is designed to me more than a website, it's a community. Embarking on participation with the "neither I want to know them" attitude may not be the most advisable approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question currently contains a large number of question following the form: "Does eating X and then drinking Y cause Z?" where X, Y & Z are:

1. watermelon, water, trees to grow in your stomach
2. fish only - no other meal, water, ???
3. fish, water or milk, weakening of digestion system
4. fish, water or milk, fever
5. fish, water or milk, cold
6. fish, water or milk, cholera
7. fish, water or milk, vitiligo
8. watermelon, water or milk, weakening of digestion system
9. watermelon, water or milk, fever
10. watermelon, water or milk, cold
11. watermelon, water or milk, cholera
12. watermelon, water or milk, vitiligo
13. watermelon, water, loose motion
14. muskmelon, water or milk, weakening of digestion system
15. muskmelon, water or milk, fever
16. muskmelon, water or milk, cold
17. muskmelon, water or milk, cholera
18. muskmelon, water or milk, vitiligo
19. muskmelon, water, loose motion
20. corn, water or milk, weakening of digestion system
21. corn, water or milk, fever
22. corn, water or milk, cold
23. corn, water or milk, cholera
24. corn, water or milk, vitiligo
25. corn, water, loose motion

To answer your question, someone would have to find 25 experiments (which have almost certainly never been done, because many of the claims are ludicrous but that's a separate issue. [Hint: Read about the cause of [cholera](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholera).)

This is too much to ask one person to do. I would suggest "Select one claim. Show it is notable. Edit to ask just that," but that might be considered a discussion of policy which you have decried.

I would link to [how to delete your account](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) but that is a policy discussion too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have edited the question. I don't have any references to justify the claim. Most of the references I had were about drinking water but the most popular myth that I have heard of is about drinkin milk after eating watermelon.I agree that the claim is  ludicrous. Wikipedea says that cholera is due to "_...eating foods and/or drinking water contaminated with the bacterium Vibrio Cholerae_."In India most of the people are vegetarian so the main cause of cholera may be drinking contaminated stuff and people made a misbelief of drinking after eating or such.Anyhow[cont]

Comment: [cont] since I do not have references to prove that the claim is notable so I guess the question[revised ver] also doesn't fit the rules of your website. In that case please close my question stating the appropriate reason as it is not too broad now and delete my account; I have followed the prescribed criteria.

Comment: Seems like the policy of deleting account is different here. I haven't yet followed the prescribed guidelines.